# Rails - On form submit, passing params to controller specific to class (i.e. classname_params)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add an input (the checkbox) to the view below that, on submit, will pass it's value to league_params in the controller, not just to params. Right now, only :name is being added to league_params on submit.

The is_disabled column (a boolean) was added through a migration after the initial creation of League if that matters.

The View

```
<%= form_for @league, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class='control-label' for="league_name">Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>      
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :is_disabled, "Is Disabled", :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.check_box :is_disabled %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                leagues_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In Controller:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @league.update(league_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @league, notice: 'League was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @league.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: So I suppose you have "def league_params" somewhere in your controller...

Comment: the params.permit at the end of the controller must allow is_disabled or it wont be saved.

Comment: Yes, it must be params.require(:league).permit(:name, :is_disabled, ...)

Comment: Bingo - still learning rails and i hadn't put 2 and 2 together that this def was responsible for that functionality. Thanks - round of upvotes on me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add something like this in the method at the end of your controller which you havent posted here:

```
def league_params
  params.require(:league).permit(:is_disabled, .. etc)
end
```

Make sure you have added the `is_disabled` here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using strong parameters, you have to 'permit' the fields that are being passed from the view. In this case and from your question, the 'name' is permitted but the field 'is_disabled' isn't.

eg

```
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
```